# Check out after first night

Tags: airlines, malaysia

I made an online booking and actually checked in and paid the first night fare. I found the hotel not appropriate and want to check out the next day. Can I check out without any additional charges?

Comment: Is this a _hotel_ booking? Why is the question tagged "airlines"? (And I suppose it depends on the hotel's policy).

Comment: maybe someone would be able to help out if you mention which hotel chain it is?

Answer (score 2):

This depends partially on how it was booked (pre-paid or free cancellation) but mostly that's in my experience a matter of negotiation.

Talk to the front desk or the hotel manager. If there is something specifically, that's not  to your satisfaction, let them know. Perhaps they can fix it (different room, repair the toilet, etc.). If it can't be fixed, let them know and ask them about their policy. Most reasonable hotels will let you go without no or maybe only one night's charge, if you leave by the official check out time, so they can resell the room for the same day. That's not great for them but often better then 1 star review on tripadvisor. Some hints on how to do this

1. Be nice and polite
2. Be specific and clear about your issues
3. Be reasonable and collaborative. If they offer a good alternative, go for it.
4. Be very firm & consistent on what's not acceptable.